# Find the maximum and minimum values of this function.

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

$f(x,y)=2x^3+y^2-24x$ where it is bounded by the region $D=\{(x,y):(x-1)^2+y^2 \leq 1, 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$. Find the global maximum and minimum of the function bounded by this region.

[image: Sketch]

This is a sketch of the region. I wanted to know what the global maximum and minimum of this function is on this region. I know that $\nabla f(x,y)=(6x^2-24, 2y)$. So already I have the critical points $(4,0), (-4,0)$. And, next we can use Lagrange's algorithm here, we have $(x-1)^2+y^2 \leq 1$, so $6x^2-24=\lambda 2(x-1)$ and $2y=\lambda 2y$. The end points of the function is $(1,1), (1, -1)$.

So how do I calculate the global maximum and minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
\nabla f(x,y)=(0.0) \iff (x,y) =(\pm2.0) \notin D, 
$$
the maximum and minimum of $f$ on $D$ can only be achieved on the boundary $\partial D$.

The boundary consists of
$$
L=\{(x,y): x=1, |y| \le 1\} 
$$
and
$$
C=\{(x,y): (x-1)^2+y^2=1, 0\le x\le 1\}=\varphi\left(\left[\frac{3\pi}{2}m\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\right),
$$
with
$$
\varphi(t)=(1+\cos t, \sin t).
$$
THe restrection, $f_{|L}$ of $f$ on $L$ given by
$$
f(1,y)=y^2-22,
$$
satisfies
$$
f(1,0)=-22=f(1,0)\le f_{|L}*x,y)\le  -21=f(1,\pm1) \quad \forall (x,y)\in L.
$$

To find the maximum/minimum of $f$ ob $C$, we can use the method of Lagrange multipliers.

Consider the function defined by

$$
F(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)-\lambda [(x-1)^2+y^2-1].
$$
At a critical point $(x,y) \in C$, the gradient of $F$ [w.r.t $(x,y)$] must be $(0,0)$, i.e.

\begin{eqnarray}
6x^2-24 &=& 2\lambda(x-1)\cr
2y&=&2\lambda y
\end{eqnarray}
We have
$$
2y=2\lambda y \iff \lambda=1 \quad or \quad y=0.
$$

If $\lambda =1$, thrn
$$
6x^2-24=2(x-1) \iff  x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{133}}{6} \notin [0,1]
$$

If $y=0$, then thanks to the constraint we get $x=0$ or $x=1$. In particular, if $x=0$, then $\lambda=12$.

Since $f(0.0)=0$, we have
$$
\min_{D}f=-22,\quad \max_{D}f=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you, very helpful sir